# Output string in PHP so you can paste it in Excel

Tags: php, string, excel

How do I format my string so someone can copy it from browser and paste it in excel and it comes out in columns?

```
"apples oranges pears"
```

comes out in excel as

```
----------------------------------------
| apples     | oranges     | pears     |
----------------------------------------
```

Something like the one above.

Comment: you mean cut&paste from browser? or output to a file?

Comment: In the case of output to file, I would use CSV

Comment: I tried `text\t` but it still comes out as a single string in a veeery long excel cell.

Comment: try copy to a notepad and then select all and ctrl+c again from the notepad before pasting to your excel. if you want "rich-text" approach without using a notepad as a proxy, organize your data to a `<table>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just produce an HTML table if you wanna enable copy and paste into excel table cells?  Last I checked that worked.

Edit:

```
<?php
#example
$var1 = "Apples";
$var2 = "Oranges";
$var3 = "Pears";
echo "<table><tr><td>$var1</td><td>$var2</td><td>$var3</td></tr></table>";
```

With this in a browser (page displayed as HTML of course), copy+paste of the text should produce your text in columns like you want.